# Error when Copying file from wwwroot local machine to other machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker' from assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I get this above error when I copying file from my local machine to other server this issue not showing when I publish in my local,
I have added the WebHost dll, but the issue never gone

someone help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to appropriately reference that assembly on the new machine just as your local machine does it.

Comment: I have do the same things, between my local and my server, the references have all included. Should I install MVC 4 in my server? cz Im already yet to install it